# How to count the number of time series rows for multiple devices in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

How do I count the number of rows for the data stored in Apache IoTDB? I want to count the number of rows of multiple devices instead of just counting the number of rows of a certain device. Anyone know how to write the query statement in IoTDB to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `select count(x1) from root.db1** group by level =1` statement in Apache IoTDB, and see if this return the results you wanted.